No valid version for 'yaxt' compiler 'nvhpc' satisfies '@24.5' on Spack
I am trying to create an environment with nvhpc24.5, yaxt and xios. But getting error.
my yaml file is:
spack:
  # add package specs to the `specs` list
  specs:
  - nvhpc@24.5+mpi
  - yaxt%nvhpc@24.5 ^gmake%gcc
  - xios%nvhpc@24.5 ^gmake%gcc ^hdf5@1.8.9:+hl ^netcdf-c+mpi
  view: true
  concretizer:
    unify: false

and spack concretize giving me following error:
==> Starting concretization pool with 2 processes
==> Error: concretization failed for the following reasons:

   1. No valid version for 'yaxt' compiler 'nvhpc' satisfies '@24.5'
   2. Cannot set the required compiler: yaxt%nvhpc

I have tried with nvhpc@24.3 but still get the same error.

Can you elaborate which version of spack that is (it seems there's no package description for yaxt in the current main) or post the yaxt package.py?

using spack v0.22.1

Been able to solve it:
spack install --add nvhpc@24.5+mpi
spack load nvhpc
spack add xios@2252%nvhpc@24.5 ^gmake%gcc ^hdf5@1.14.4-3
spack add yaxt%nvhpc@24.5 ^gmake%gcc
spack concretize
spack install

